# How to enable logs in Websphere Application Server for debug in start-up script?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, ibm-was

Is there any way through which we can enable **debug** logs in start up script of Websphere Application Server, preferably V8.5? A guy told me long back that there is a command we need to write in **startServer.bat**, I can't recall that.

I know how to enable logs through WAS admin console, viz. through '**logging and tracing**', but how can I do that in start up script for debug? Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

The `-trace` argument to the `startServer` script will cause the `logs/<server>/startServer.log` file to have additional details about the server start process (rather than the server process).  See the [startServer command](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_startserver.html?lang=en) topic in the Knowledge Center for additional information.